# Getting MySQL Connector/J + JDBC to work

Tags: mysql, jdbc, xampp

I've been trying to get MySQL Connector/J set up for the past hour but I am not getting anywhere.

I tried following a lot of tutorials, and am using the code on this page to test my connection:

http://www.stardeveloper.com/articles/display.html?article=2003090201&page=4

I have tried putting the path to the connector .jar file in the `CLASSPATH` environment variable, but that didn't get me anywhere. I also tried putting it in `%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/ext` and it STILL doesn't work??

When I run the code that is provided on that page, I get the following error which isn't very useful.

> Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

I feel like it isn't finding the jar file but I have no idea what else to do.

I don't know if it is worth mentioning, but I installed MySQL through XAMPP.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use Eclipse, adding a MySQL jar to the classpath is 1, 2, 3 => [three clicks](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Eclipse/article.html#classpath)

Otherwise, when you run your application you can add jar(s) to the classpath using a `-cp` option:

```java
java -cp mysql.jar MySqlExample.java
```

You can follow [this simple example](http://www.vogella.de/articles/MySQLJava/article.html) on how to get Java and MySQL talk to each other.